# Problem with a dataset not being properly labelled

Tags: machine-learning, multi-class, semi-supervised-learning

I have a labelled dataset but these classes are not perfect. Some classes should be combined into one, whilst others have too few data-points for training. My main concern is the former not the latter. I was wondering if it makes sense to use clustering (unsupervised learning) to clean the classes as a pre-step for supervised learning (any examples?). Are there any other techniques to join and organize the classes? My intention is to classify future new data-points to a single class, should I stick to unsupervised learning?

In a different post, someone suggested using semi-supervised learning (currently trying to understand this), but that only applies if you are certain about some of the classes, right?. To give an example imagine I have a dataset of measurements for different plants and all are labelled using their common names, however some, with two different common names, are actually a single species and should be relabelled as such. I cannot be sure which should be joined and which are "clean".